# Battery Life: I don't have one, it's a desktop

Tags: power-management, battery

Settings>Power says I have only 2hrs and half left of battery power, but I don't get one. I installed Ubuntu 18.4 on a Cherry mini PC, Intel, 4GB of RAM, 32 GB ROM + 250 GB SSD SATA Kingston. There is no battery, only power addapter. Please tell me my new PC will not explode or die in minus 2hrs. How can I tell Ubuntu that's a desktop not a notebook? Lines?

Comment: Whats the output of `laptop-detect -v` ?

Comment: We're a laptop (non device ACPI batteries found

Comment: -V returns: Version: 0.16

Comment: Could be there are UPS devices or a source that provide emergency power, can you clarify ? Whats your device model ?

Comment: No other power source than input 220v, output 5v, 2.500mA plugged in. Remove cable, mini PC is dead

Comment: Modelo Cherry CYX_T11 bought on Banggood

Comment: @TomásWoodall just ignore it